# Ubuntu Studio and Midi over Ethernet

Tags: networking, sound, ethernet, ubuntu-studio, midi

Is there a standard, commonly used program for handling Midi over Ethernet included in Ubuntu Studio? If not, any recommendations?

I would like to run VCVRack on a number of computers on my LAN, and have them clocked together and talking to each other. They are pretty old computers, and get bogged down if I throw to much at any one machine individually.

Windows has RTP-MIDI, MacOS has Network MIDI built into it's Audio MIDI Setup program. I'm running Ubuntu Studio 21.04. Is there anything built in?
**[Thanks @Sebastian, QmidiNet does MIDI over UDP, and is installed with Ubuntu Studio]**

Clarification: Ideally, I'm looking for something that is interoperable with the Bonjour, TCP-based approach used by both MacOS and RTP-MIDI on Windows, for a local network of heterogeneous hosts.

Comment: Have you looked at [QmidiNet](https://qmidinet.sourceforge.io/)? It should be pre-installed on Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. Someone had told me they used "qMIDI" on Debian, and searches for that name led me in the wrong direction to a Windows MIDI file editor. They must have meant QmidiNet. Looks like QmidiNet is the answer to the question of what's built into Ubuntu Studio. I'm not sure if I'll be able to make it interoperable with the RTP-MIDI approaches on my Mac and Windows machines.